# Securing a RESTEasy WS

Tags: jboss7.x, resteasy

I'm developing two projects using Netbeans 7.2:

**1:** a jee6 web project (Provided): an RestEasy webservices, it take data from a PostgreSQL database using JPA (EclipseLink 2.3) and deploy on JBoss 7.1.1.Final

jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
 <!-- URL to access the web module -->
 <context-root>/dbo</context-root>        
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<!-- Auto scan REST service -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

JSONService.java:

```
package com.ostudio.dbo.rest;
import com.ostudio.dbo.model.Member;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;    

@Path("/members")
@RequestScoped
public class JSONService {
   @Inject
   private EntityManager em;

   @GET
   @Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public List<Member> listAllMembers() {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      final List<Member> results = em.createQuery("select m from Member m order by m.name").getResultList();
      return results;
   }
}
```

**2:** the second project is the client (Consumer): a jee6 web project: an RestEasy client, its secure is based on jaas conected ldap server and deploy on JBoss 7.1.1.Final

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>home-module</display-name>
    <!-- Protected Areas -->
    <security-constraint>
         <display-name>Admin Area</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Only_admins</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/pages/protected/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>For admin role only</description>
            <role-name>administrators</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- Validation By Form -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/pages/public/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/pages/public/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <!-- Allowed Roles -->
    <security-role>
        <description>Administrators</description>
        <role-name>administrators</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <jboss-web>
     <!-- URL to access the web module -->
     <context-root>/</context-root>

     <!-- Realm that will be used -->
     <security-domain>SecurityRealm</security-domain>
    </jboss-web>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
      <dependencies> 
         <module name="org.primefaces" meta-inf="export">
            <imports>
               <include path="META-INF" />
            </imports>
         </module>  
         <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" meta-inf="export">
            <imports>
               <include path="META-INF" />
            </imports>
         </module>  
      </dependencies>
  </deployment>   
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

DBOResteasyClient.java:

```
package com.ostudio.homemodule.dbo;

import com.ostudio.homemodule.model.Member;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse;
import org.primefaces.json.JSONArray;
import org.primefaces.json.JSONException;
import org.primefaces.json.JSONObject;

/**
 *
 * @author josuna
 */
@ManagedBean(name="dboBean")
@RequestScoped
public class DBOResteasyClient {
    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/dbo/rest";
    ClientRequest webResource;
    ClientResponse response;
    private List<Member> members;
    private Member member;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DBOResteasyClient.class.toString());

    public DBOResteasyClient() {
        final String Path = "/members";
        webResource = new ClientRequest(BASE_URI+Path);
    }

   // @Named provides access the return value via the EL variable name "members" in the UI (e.g.,
   // Facelets or JSP view)
   @Produces
   @Named
    public List<Member> getMembers(){
        return this.members;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void listAllMembers() {
        try{
             ClientRequest resource = webResource;
        response = resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class); 

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatus());    }   

        }catch(Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String jsonData = (String) response.getEntity(String.class); 

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);

            members = new ArrayList<Member>();

       for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
       {    
         JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         member = new Member();
         member.setId(json_data.getLong("id"));
         member.setName(json_data.getString("name"));
         member.setEmail(json_data.getString("email"));
         member.setPhoneNumber(json_data.getString("phoneNumber"));         

         members.add(member);
    }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            log.info("ERROR EN listAllMembers: DBOResteasyClient: home-module");
        }       

   //  log.info("listAllMembers: size["+ members.size()+"]");

        log.info("Output from Server .... \n");
        log.info(jsonData);
    }

    public void close(){

    }
}
```

**My Question is:**
I need to protect the webservice.
I use a jboss 7.1 realm to secure the client, I need to protect the webservice resteasy but I don't want use other realm because it ask for auth again, is there a form to protect the webservice and use the client auth to access the webservice without it ask for auth again?

Comment: You have provided way to much "unnecessary" info. Reduce the content of question to precise context.

Comment: @MukulGoel I need to protect the webservice, it would be using tokens, or oauth, do you know a full example on RESTEasy?

Comment: So how does all that information you have provided useful to me in giving answer ? You know why your question has not received any answer , your question description is vague. Reduce the content and provide whats relevant. Reformat it. I am not answering this till the question is worthy of an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you want to authenticate/authorize your user. If you want to *secure* the connection you should use TLS with HTTPS.
If your connection is already secured by TLS you can use HTTP Basic Authentication and use a `SecurityInterceptor`:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class RestSecurityInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor
{
  // @EJB XXX xx (you can use Beans);

  @Override
  public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method)
     throws UnauthorizedException
  {
    // if(request.getPreprocessedPath().startsWith("/secure")){}
    // perhaps you will limit it to a special path

    // Then get the HTTP-Authorization header and base64 decode it
    request.getHttpHeaders().getRequestHeader("Authorization");

    // check whatever you want with your EJB
    // if it fails, 
    // throw new UnauthorizedException("Username/Password does not match");
  }
}
```

Your client should implement preemptive HTTP basic authentication.